# AWS Cognito with AWS SSO

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

is it possible to use AWS cognito and its user pool (say I have user helloworld) with AWS IAM identity center (SSO successor)?

What I want is that I will be using AWS SSO and the users for logging in will be from the AWS cognito.

Basically, how do I use cognito user pool as IDP for AWS SSO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, it is not supported yet.

> Amazon Cognito is a service that helps you manage identities for your customer facing applications; it is not a supported identity source in IAM Identity Center. You can create and manage your workforce identities in IAM Identity Center or in your external identity source including Microsoft Active Directory, Okta Universal Directory, Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), or another supported IdP.

Reference - https://aws.amazon.com/iam/identity-center/faqs/